# Restar valores de columnas en particular

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Hola estoy trabajando en un dataframe el cual tiene solamente 2 filas y 53 columnas. Estoy intentando restar las variables numéricas de las columnas pero no encuentro la formula. Estoy buscando el inverso de esta función:

```
colSums(Arg[,4:53])      #Arg es la base de datos y de la fila 4 a la 53 son variables numericas.
```

Esta función me entrega la suma para cada columna numérica de la numero 4 a la 5 de la siguiente forma:

```
#   1970         1971         1972         1973         1974         1975         1976         1977         1978         1979         1980      
#16887916065  16741730062  16543468917  17708036169  18137788043  17315879623  18603656526  24294813265  25249135770  29155245829  34144024608 
# ( Los datos van desde 1970 hasta 2019)
```

Lo que necesito es restar la primera fila con la segunda y que me entregue los resultados para las columnas elegidas.
Adjunto ejemplo de tabla!

| Country | IndicatorNames | 1971 | 1972 | 1973 | 1974 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARG | Exports of goods and services | 56000 | 10000 | 5000 | 35000 |
| ARG | Imports of goods and services | 4000 | 10000 | 3500 | 1000 |

y el output que necesito seria esto pero para todos los años:

| Country | IndicatorNames | 1971 | 1972 | 1973 | 1974 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARG | Exports of goods and services | 56000 | 10000 | 5000 | 35000 |
| ARG | Imports of goods and services | 4000 | 1000 | 3500 | 1000 |
| ARG | *Resultado* | 52000 | 9000 | 1500 | 34000 |

Ojala esta vez haber explicado bien y muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando tu ejemplo:

```
Arg <- read.table(text="Country IndicatorNames  1971    1972    1973    1974
ARG 'Exports of goods and services' 56000   10000   5000    35000
ARG 'Imports of goods and services' 4000    10000   3500    1000", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```

Usando R base podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Arg$signo = ifelse(Arg$IndicatorNames == 'Exports of goods and services', 1, -1)
colSums(Arg[, 3:6]*Arg$signo)

 1971  1972  1973  1974 
52000     0  1500 34000
```

La idea es simple, generamos un `signo` en función del indicador y luego simplemente sumamos las columnas elegidas mediante `colSums()`

La misma idea puedes implementarla con `dplyr/tidyverse` pero haciendo una agrupación y sumando:

```
library(tidyverse)

Arg %>% 
  mutate(signo=ifelse(IndicatorNames == 'Exports of goods and services', 1, -1)) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(2:5), ~ sum(.x * signo))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Country `1971` `1972` `1973` `1974`
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ARG      52000      0   1500  34000
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no comprendí bien la pregunta. Pero creo que basta simplemente con hacer la resta de la segunda fila a la primera fila, en las variables (columnas) seleccionadas:

```
   Arg[1,3:6]-Arg[2,3:6]
   1971 1972 1973  1974
1 52000    0 1500 34000
```